# Error Exception when get data from json i laravel

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, web

I'm trying to read data from an External API that I found on the internet, I've followed several articles on the internet but there are still errors like the one below, does anyone know how I can get data from the JSON?

erro :

```
ErrorException {#196 ▼
  #message: "Illegal string offset 'verses'"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\laragon\www\distrik24blog\storage\framework\views\e523d302202180142edce531702b14dc31954a07.php"
  #line: 42
  #severity: E_WARNING
}
```

controller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class alkitabcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function fetchInitialData(){
        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->get("https://api-alkitab.herokuapp.com/v2/passage/kejadiam/1?ver=tb");
        $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $data = json_decode($json_string);
        return view('khotbahdanrenungan/alkitab', compact('data'));
    }

    public function getDataAlkitab(Request $request){
        $kitab = $request->input('kitab');
        $pasal = $request->input('pasal');

        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->get("https://api-alkitab.herokuapp.com/v2/passage/$kitab/$pasal?ver=tb");
        $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $data = json_decode($json_string);
        return view('khotbahdanrenungan/alkitab', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

web :

```
Route::get('/alkitab','alkitabcontroller@fetchInitialData');
Route::post('/searchdata','alkitabcontroller@getDataAlkitab');
```

blade code :

```
<div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @foreach ($data as $item)
                    <label for="kitab"><span>Markus</span><span>24</span></label>
                    <p>{{ $item['verses']['content']}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

json structure :

```
{
    "title": "Yohanes 1:1-51",
    "book_number": 43,
    "chapter": 1,
    "verses": [
        {
            "verse": 1,
            "content": "Pada mulanya adalah Firman; Firman itu bersama-sama dengan Allah dan Firman itu adalah Allah."
        },
        {
            "verse": 2,
            "content": "Ia pada mulanya bersama-sama dengan Allah."
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$json_string` to return `json string` so you need to pass `true`  to `json_decode` as second parameter or else it return `object`

```
 $client = new Client;
    $response = $client->get("https://api-alkitab.herokuapp.com/v2/passage/kejadiam/1?ver=tb");
    $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(json_decode($json_string, true));
```

this will return array

```
Array
(
    [title] => Amos 1:1-15
    [book_number] => 30
    [chapter] => 1
    [verses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [verse] => 1
                    [content] => Perkataan yang dinyatakan kepada Amos, salah seorang peternak domba dari Tekoa, tentang Israel pada zaman Uzia, raja Yehuda, dan dalam zaman Yerobeam, anak Yoas, raja Israel, dua tahun sebelum gempa bumi.
                )

            [1] => Array
```

Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> json_decode ( string $json , bool|null $associative = null , int
> $depth = 512 , int $flags = 0 ) : mixed

> **$associative**
>
> When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; when
> false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When null, JSON
> objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects depending on
> whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags.

**Updated**

Also your loop need to change

```
 @foreach ($data['verses'] as $item)
                    <label for="kitab"><span>Markus</span><span>24</span></label>
                    <p>{{ $item['content']}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    @endforeach
```

if you are `json_decode($json_string)` then

```
  @foreach ($data->verses as $item)
                        <label for="kitab"><span>Markus</span><span>24</span></label>
                        <p>{{ $item['content']}}</p>
                        <hr>
                        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered dumpign your variables to see how the structure is truly defined? `dd($data)` or `dd($item)` (within `php`) will show you the variable and its contents.

If I read your code as such, your json structure is a dump of `$data` and therefore looping through `$data` gives you each individual key, and the key `title` does not have a sub-key called `verses`.

However, if it *is* meant to exist, you can use [`null coalesce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to capture if it doesn't exist:
`{{ $item['verses']['content'] ?? '' }}`